# Trying to use Regex match an iOS phone number using iOS Shortcuts

Tags: ios, regex, unicode, phone-number, ios-shortcut

I'm creating an iOS shortcut that starts with checking whether the clipboard currently holds a copied phone number.

So far, my regex is the following:

```
^[\d\()-‑+  ]+$
```

Although while typing a regular phone number using the phone keyboard, e.g., `+972 12-345-6789`, it works just fine; it seems like when copied directly from the default `Phone` application, it does not find it as a match.

I should mention that after digging for a while, it seems like the phone number copied from the *Phone* application is associated with some extra special characters used for `Left-To-Right Embedding` and such. Using a Unicode decoder gave me the following string:

```
&#x202A;+972&#x00A0;12‑345‑6789&#x202C;
```

I'm not even sure whether this is the reason, but it might have some connection to it. If so - is there any way in which I can use `iOS Shortcuts` to decode the clipboard text into a Unicode format and remove those extra characters? And in case there is no connection between the two, what else might be the problem?

Comment: What if you add the support for all these chars to the pattern? `^[\d()+\p{Zs}\p{Pd}\p{Cf}]+$`. `\p{Zs}` - all spaces without the tabs and line breaks, `\p{Pd}` will match any dashes, and `\p{Cf}` matches the bidirectional marks and more other control format chars.

Comment: Does that approach work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew! That did the trick! please make sure to answer the question so I'll be able to mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the support for all these chars to the pattern:

```swift
^[\d()+\p{Zs}\p{Pd}\p{Cf}]+$`
```

Note:

- `\p{Zs}` matches all whitespaces without the tabs and line breaks (add `\t` to the brackets if you need to support TAB)
- `\p{Pd}` will match any dashes
- `\p{Cf}` matches the bidirectional marks and more other control format chars.

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative solution

It is possible to paste the copied clipboard text into a `Text` action which removes any additional formatting.[image: iOS 14 shortcut- using 'Text' action to remove formatting]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Solution

Shortcuts has a native command to extract phone numbers.  Just use “Get Phone Numbers from _______” command in your shortcut.  It recognizes all phone number formats.

Example:
[image: code block Shortcut example]